# use java script variable in ActionLink mvc3 razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a textbox where i must to write a value, how to pass this value in my controller if I call my controller using ActionLink, this is my code:

view:

```
@Html.TextBox("tisch", "", new { @class = "teschChange"})
@Html.ActionLink("Apply Command", "ApplyCommand", "Work")
```

and this is te script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function test() {
        $(".teschChange").change(function () {
            var tisch = $(this).attr('value');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I must to send tisch in ApplyCommandController
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an action link, use a standard link:

```
<a id="l" href="@Url.Action("ApplyCommand", "Work")">Apply Command</a>
```

Then, you can use this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function test() {
        $(".teschChange").change(function () {
            var tisch = $(this).attr('value');
            $("#l").attr("href", "@Url.Action("ApplyCommand", "Work")/" + tisch);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Which will assign a href of: `/Work/ApplyCommand/tisch`.

Comment: Object[object Object] has no method 'href'

Answer (score 0):

this was the correct script:

```
 $("#l").attr("href", "@Url.Action("ApplyCommand", "Work")?tisch=" + tisch);
```